# How to use stanford corenlp

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working on Stanford NER task, and I want to use the Stanford CoreNLp, but I need it as a web service, by sending it the sentences and it will retrieve the sentences with resolved

So, anyone knows a service to do that, or how can I benefit this website
Thanks

Comment: Will this work for you? https://github.com/turian/stanford-pos-tagger-service

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below links

https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/stanford-thrift

or

https://github.com/nlohmann/StanfordCoreNLPXMLServer